# iOS Push Notificattion production certificate Common Name issue

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

While I am attempting to upload Production certificate on Parse.com for Push notificatation.

There is error message

> Unsupported certificate type. Common Name (CN) must contain one of:
>   Apple Production IOS Push Services, Apple Development IOS Push
>   Services, Pass Type ID, Apple Development Mac Push Services, Apple
>   Production Mac Push Services.

After some research I came to know that.
While we are exporting Production certificate from Apple,

Common Name before was : Apple Production IOS Push Services:[Bundle name]
And Now : Apple Push Services:[Bundle name]

May be this is the reason Parse fails to validate certificate.

Please give solution if any.

Comment: I am also facing same issue...Hope I will find any solution here

Comment: try this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Comment: There is an issue with not having your bundle identifier in the following format "com.domainName.Name" the notification certificates don't seem to work unless its using this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems **problem is solved** now by Parse.
You can face error

> Could not connect to Apple with this certificate

If so, **revoke** your APNS certificate and **regenerate** it.
And then create .p12 file with this new certificate. and upload it.

I have successfully uploaded .p12 file.